# Conditional expectation of second moment given sum of iid variables.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

We have $\xi_i \geq 0$, $\forall i = \overline{1,n}$ (i.i.d. variables). 
Assume that $S_n = \xi_1 +...+ \xi_n$.

It is easy to show that $\mathrm{E} (\xi_1\vert S_n = 1) = \frac{1}{n}$.

Now we want to look at the second moment: $\mathrm{E}(\xi_1^2\vert S_n = 1)$.

1) Since $0\leq\xi_i\leq 1$ then $\xi_i\geq \xi_i^2,\: \forall i=\overline{1,n},$ finally, $\mathrm{E}(\xi_1^2\vert S_n = 1) \leq \mathrm{E}(\xi_1\vert S_n = 1) = \frac{1}{n}$.

2) On the other hand,
by Jensen's  inequality we have: $(\mathrm{E}(\xi_1\vert S_n = 1))^2\leq \mathrm{E}(\xi_1^2\vert S_n = 1),$ where$(\mathrm{E}(\xi_1\vert S_n = 1))^2 = \frac{1}{n^2}$.

The question is: how can we prove that the second moment has order of $\frac{1}{n^2}$; namely how we can get upper bound as $\frac{c}{n^2}$, where $c$ is a constant?

Comment: Which is the distribution the $ξ_i$?

Comment: It isn't mentioned. But we can assume that density is a known function f(x).

Comment: Ok, but then how do you know that $ξ_i<1$? in 1).

Comment: Here you kinda need to assume that $P(S_1 = 1) \neq 0$ otherwise conditioning on improbable event is a good way to end up with wrong results.

Comment: If the random variables $(\xi_i)$ are i.i.d. exponential, then $$E(\xi_1^2\mid S_n)=\frac{2S_n^2}{n(n+1)}.$$

Comment: @Did and how have you shown that? By the integrating the conditional density?

Comment: More or less, yes.

Comment: @Stef because we have condition that $S_n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove it, because it might not be true.

Suppose $\xi_i$ take nonnegative integer values. Then the only way to have $S_n = 1$ is that one $\xi_i = 1$ while all the rest are $0$.  So  for such a distribution, $E(\xi_i^2 | S_n = 1) = 1/n$, and indeed
$E(\xi_i^p | S_n = 1) = 1/n$ for all positive $p$.

More generally, if $P(0 < \xi_i < \epsilon) = 0$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, then
$\xi_i^2 \ge \epsilon \xi_i$ a.s. so $E(\xi_1^2 | S_n) \ge \epsilon E(\xi_1 | S_n)$.