# Conditional expectation, sum of exponential i.i.d variables. Integral of conditional density.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

We have $\xi_i \geq 0$, $\forall i = \overline{1,n}$ (exponetial i.i.d. variables). 
Assume that $S_n = \xi_1 +...+ \xi_n$.

It is easy to show that $\mathrm{E} (\xi_1\vert S_n = 1) = \frac{1}{n}$.

$$f_{\xi\vert\eta} = \frac{f_{\xi\eta}(x,y)}{f_{\eta}(y)}$$

On the other hand: $\mathrm{E} (\xi_1\vert S_n = 1) = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{xf^{*(n-1)}(1-x)}{f^{*n}(1)}\:\mathrm{d}x$, where $$f^{*n}(x) = \idotsint\limits_{z_{1}+...+z_{n} = x}f(z_1)...f(z_n)\:\mathrm{d}z_1\dots\:\mathrm{d}z_n;\quad f(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$$

Am I right? I suppose that I am not.

I think that in exponential case $f^{*n}(t) = \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}$ because of the fact that sum of exponential i.i.d. variables has gamma distribution.

For example, let $n=2$.

$$\frac{1}{2} = \mathrm{E} (\xi_1\vert S_n = 1) = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{x\lambda e^{-\lambda (1-x)}}{\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda }}\:\mathrm{d}x \neq \frac{1}{2}$$

So tell me please where I'm wrong and how to calculate such expectations correctly.

P.S. This question has appeared after my other question where @Did commented an answer to an exponential case, but I can't calculate the result. Here is a link.
[Conditional expectation of second moment given sum of iid variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039937/conditional-expectation-of-second-moment-given-sum-of-iid-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the error was in the formula for the conditional expectation. 
Correct formula:
$$\mathrm{E} (\xi_1\vert S_n = 1) = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{xf(x)f^{*(n-1)}(1-x)}{f^{*n}(1)}\:\mathrm{d}x.$$